# How can I re distribute my weight such that expected outcome is the same

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to calculate expected outcome after resting a price, I tried using scaling matrix but it did not work. Appreciate any help.

```
double originalPrice = {5, 8, 18, 58, 80, 49.399167162403300}

double originalWeight = {0.34146341463414637, 0.3902439024390244, 0.14634146341463414, 0.024390243902439025, 0.024390243902439025, 0.07317073170731707}
```

after some iterations iterations my new prices and new weights are now,

```
double newPrices1 = [7.0, 8.0, 20.0, 58.0, 81.0, 49.3991671624033]
double newWeight1 =  [0.3575704958570497, 0.3902439024390244, 0.15629694702450886, 0.024390243902439025, 0.024390243902439025, 0.04710816687453892]
```

note: the EX (expected value) of originalPrice and newPrice1 is the same, you calculate by taking the product of respective price to respective weight and then take the total sum of it.

in the next iteration the first price returns to its original value e.g we call it newPrices2

```
double newPrices2 = [5.0, 8.0, 20.0, 58.0, 82.0, 49.3991671624033]
```

I want to find new weights, that would keep my expected outcome the same

```
double newWeight2 = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6]
```

I tried scaling the vectors but it did not help, here is the code algorithm i tried.

```
public static double[] redistributeWeight(double[] prices, 
 double[] weights, double[] originalWeights) {
        double totalOriginalPrice = 0.0;
        double totalCurrentPrice = 0.0;

        // Calculate the total original price and current price
        for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
            totalOriginalPrice += originalWeights[i] * prices[i];
            totalCurrentPrice += weights[i] * prices[i];
        }

        // Calculate the scaling factor
        double scaleFactor = totalOriginalPrice / totalCurrentPrice;

        // Redistribute the weights based on the scaling factor
        for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
            weights[i] *= scaleFactor;
        }

        return weights;
    }
```

Comment: What restrictions are on the weights? If none, set w[0] = ex / p[0] and set all other weights to 0.0 (which is ridiculous).

Comment: Right now there are no restrictions but that would not be the best solution. I would like to keep the weights somewhat relative to its price.

Comment: The only restrictions i have right now is that the weight should not be below 0, which is quite trivial, because probability cannot be negative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are literally an infinite number of ways to do this.  It all depends on how you want your weights to be distributed.

For example you can decide that your weights have to follow a rule like this:

```
weight is proportional to Math.exp((price - k)*(price - k))
```

Now as `k` goes to - infinity, the average price goes to the bottom price in your list.  Given `k` you can easily calculate what the average price should be.  As `k` goes to + infinity, the average price goes to the top price

There is no analytical way to figure out what `k` should be, but you can easily search with something like this untested code.

```
double k0 = 0.0;
double k1 = 1.0;
double epsilon = 0.00001;
while (averagePrice(k1) < desiredPrice) {
    k0 = k1;
    k1 += k1;
}
if (desiredPrice < averagePrice(k0)) {
    k0 = -1;
    k1 = 0;
    while (desiredPrice < averagePrice(k0)) {
        k1 = k0;
        k0 -= k0;
    }
}
while (k0 + epsilon) {
    kMid = (k0 + k1)/2;
    double averageMid = averagePrice(kMid);
    if (averageMid < desiredPrice) {
        k0 = kMid;
    } else if (desiredPrice < averageMid) {
        k1 = kMid;
    } else {
        return weightsFor(kMid);
    }
}
... average out weightsFor(k0) and weightsFor(k1) to get desiredAverage
```

If you have a lot of prices fairly evenly distributed around your desired one, this will give weights that look a lot like a normal curve averaging near your desired one.

But you can literally choose any family of shapes that you want for the prices and the same idea will work.  And if you're tolerant of changing the shape, making `epsilon` larger will cut the search faster at the cost of having the final distribution a little less perfectly the ideal that you chose.